# Android: Why can't I programmaticaly pair to a bluetooth device, even with BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED and setPairingConfirmation

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, dialog, pairing

I am currently trying to programmaticaly pair my Android device (4.4.2 KitKat) to a bluetooth dongle in a .NET project.

Normal pairing with user input (the pass key dialog) works, but I would like to bypass the user input.

After some reasearch ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047995/programmatically-pair-bluetooth-device-without-the-user-entering-pin) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337032/how-can-i-avoid-or-dismiss-androids-bluetooth-pairing-notification-when-i-am-do)) I managed to come up with some code, but the dialog still appears.

Below I have my permisions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
```

The minimum api level is set to 19, so I should have the Bluetooth privileged permission.

The code for pairing the specific device:

```
    final String SERVER_MAC = "00:1A:7D:DA:71:07";
    final BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    final ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> server = new ArrayList<>();
    ba.startDiscovery();
    BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice bd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d(TAG,"Found device: " + bd.getName() + " : " + bd.getAddress());
                if(bd.getAddress().equals(SERVER_MAC)){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Server bluetooth found");
                    server.add(bd);
                    Log.d(TAG,"creating bond");
                    bd.createBond();
                    ba.cancelDiscovery();

                }
            }
            else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)){
                Log.d(TAG,"setting info");
                setBluetoothPairingPin(server.get(0));
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(btReceiver, filter);
    IntentFilter pairingRequest = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    registerReceiver(btReceiver,pairingRequest);
```

And the ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST method:

```
    byte[] pairingPin = "123456".getBytes();
    try{
        Log.d(TAG,"Trying to set pin");
        bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class).invoke(bluetoothDevice,pairingPin);
        Log.d(TAG,"Success setting pin");
        try{
            bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(bluetoothDevice, true);

            Log.d(TAG,"Success setting pairing confirmtion");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,"Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"Exception 2: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Any information would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` cannot be used in 3rd party app. Your app should be system app to use that permission. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED).

Comment: @Aigori thanks, I eventually finished the project using user input for pairing, but it helps to know that it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED and it will work on Android version prior 7. On those, only BLUETOOTH_ADMIN is required.
It was then changed by: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-7.0.0_r24